# Uploading an app to iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I'm making a small app for personal use that cannot (as far as I'm aware) be done as a web page. It utilises Cordova and the Ionic framework. The only reason I require Cordova is for bluetooth support.

Is there any way to put the app on just my phone without paying the $99? As far as I can see there isn't the possibility of that?

Comment: There is no other way.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this. You have to join Apple Developer program to install your application into your actual device.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PhoneGap Developer App](http://app.phonegap.com/) or [Ionic View](http://view.ionic.io/) to run apps on your phone. However neither support the Cordova Bluetooth plugins yet.